# Spring Cloud Consul Deregister Failing

Tags: spring, cloud, consul

I am using Spring Boot / Cloud / Consul (1.0.0.M2 and have tried current code as of 10/6/2015). I'm trying to register/deregister a service that uses a dynamic port and a dynamic id.

I have the following bootstrap:

```
spring:
 cloud:
  consul:
   config:
    enabled: true
    host: localhost
    port: 8500
```

And application.yml

```
spring:
 main: 
  show-banner: false
 application:
  name: helloService
 cloud:
  consul:
   config: 
    prefix: config
    defaultContext: helloService
   discovery: 
    instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance.id:${random.value}}
    healthCheckPath: /${spring.application.name}/health
    healthCheckInterval: 15s
endpoints:
 shutdown:
  enabled: true
```

And in the Key Values under config/application/server.port = 0 for a dynamic port.

The service is registered correctly during startup:

```
{
"consul": {
    "ID": "consul",
    "Service": "consul",
    "Tags": [],
    "Address": "",
    "Port": 8300
},
"helloService-6596692c4e8af31ddd1589b0d359899f": {
    "ID": "helloService-6596692c4e8af31ddd1589b0d359899f",
    "Service": "helloService",
    "Tags": [],
    "Address": "",
    "Port": 50307
}  }
```

After issuing the shutdown:

```
curl http://localhost:50307/shutdown -X POST
{"message":"Shutting down, bye..."}
```

The service is still registered and the health check starts failing.

```
{
    "consul": {
        "ID": "consul",
        "Service": "consul",
        "Tags": [],
        "Address": "",
        "Port": 8300
    },
    "helloService-6596692c4e8af31ddd1589b0d359899f": {
        "ID": "helloService-6596692c4e8af31ddd1589b0d359899f",
        "Service": "helloService",
        "Tags": [],
        "Address": "",
        "Port": 50307
} }
```

What is missing?

Comment: Seeing the same thing for my Spring boot app. Found a fix for your problem?

Comment: I think the issue had to do with the random-id in the service id and refreshing the application. If you use ${spring.application.name}::${spring.application.instance.id::${random.value}}

Comment: for the instance id and then refresh the application context (/admin/refresh) a new instance id is generated.  I switched the instance id to use the PID and that is working: ${spring.application.name}::${spring.application.instance.id::${PID}}